# Adobe Air - Drag image to desktop

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

Is it possible to drag an image from the inside of an Adobe Air app to the desktop or a folder? This code I'm using is only able to drag an image from app to app: (I'm using Windows XP)

```
myObject.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mDown);

function mDown(MouseEvent):void
{
var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(myObject.width,myObject.height);
bitmapData.draw(myObject);

var myClip:Clipboard = new Clipboard();
myClip.setData(ClipboardFormats.BITMAP_FORMAT, bitmapData);

var objPoint:Point = new Point( -  myObject.mouseX, -  myObject.mouseY);
NativeDragManager.doDrag(myObject, myClip, bitmapData, objPoint);
}
```

Is there something that needs to be added?
Thanks
Uli

Comment: Though this is no answer, maybe it'll point you in the right direction. At the moment, you're dragging a pure bitmap stream, that is, the raw image data. It would need to be put in the confines of a file first before you can drop it on the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

you may need to use the `URLFilePromise` class

[see here for details](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/air/desktop/URLFilePromise.html)